# Nodejs logger middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I want to have request and response for every request in one express 
based application inside log file. I want to have only requests for jsons and regarding responses. Can you suggest me middle-ware or another solution which is best to this purpose?

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

Try [Morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/) and use a custom filter that skips non json requests.

```
app.use(
  morgan(
    ':method :url :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms',
    { skip: skipNonJSON }
  )
)
```

`skipNonJSON` could be defined as follow,

```
function skipNonJSON(request, respnose) {
  return !(/\.json$/.test(req.url))
}
```

if by json requests you mean URLs that end with `.json`. For JSON payloaded requests, look into the headers

```
function skipNonJSON(request, respnose) {
  return req.headers["Content-Type"] !== "application/json";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I started to experiment with Morgan half a hour ago.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) logger which is highly configurable.

```
const winston = require('winston');
let logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: 'file.log' })
  ]
 });
logger.info('Your custom data to log');
```

Comment: Thank you! With Winston is possible to log response body also. This is exactly what I needed for.